# How to rephrase 'questions that concern me'

Tags: synonyms

I'm wondering how is the following statement could be improved and used in formal English:

> I've added some questions that concern me.
>
> I've added some questions I'm worried about.
>
> I've added some questions which I'd like you to take into account.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are asking questions about topics of concern.

The main problem with your first two sentences is that you are not concerned or worried about *the questions themselves*, but that is what you have stated. Rather, your inquiries are intended to help resolve your concerns.

Try one of these:

1. I'm concerned about several things and wonder if you could answer a few questions.
2. Below are some questions about my concerns.
3. I have included several questions that could help to address my concerns.

There are many variations on this theme. The main idea is to state that you have concerns, and introduce your list of questions.

Also, I would avoid the phrase "that concern me" because this phrase can also mean "having to do with me" or "relating to me in some way." It's ambiguous.